# How can I substitute or make soft brown sugar?

Tags: substitutions, brown-sugar

I have just moved to Germany.  I haven't yet been able to find brown sugar of the type we have in Australia ie: soft, small grained, slightly sticky in that it holds its shape well when you dig a spoonful out.  The only brown sugars I have seen are granular.  You can also buy molasses.

Crushing the granular sugar is both labour-intensive and not that successful.

Any ideas on the ratios of different sugar products required to produce a 'soft brown sugar'?

As context, I tend to use soft brown sugars in things like fruit crumble toppings, as a base for a very dark caramel sauce, and also as a substitute for palm sugar when (as in Germany) it's difficult to get hold of.  The granular sugars don't behave in quite the same way when melting/added to hot sauces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put the regular (refined white) sugar and molasses (about 2 tablespoons per cup of sugar) in a food processor and give it a spin. Use more or less molasses as needed to get the color and consistency that you want.

Comment: +1 This is also how they fake brown sugar when it is much more expensive than regular one

Comment: +1: Molasses + white sugar is what brown sugar is. The ratio for light brown is usually around 1 part molasses to 25 parts white sugar, and 2:25 for dark brown sugar.

Comment: Thanks for the ratios - I thought it might be something like this, but wasn't sure of the quantities to try.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but a good substitution for brown sugar that is generally easy to find internationally is [Jaggery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggery).  I find it substitutes very well.  You should be able to find it at any Indian grocery.

Comment: Thanks - I haven't yet had time to find Jaggery but will be on the look out.

Answer (score 1):

I've only done this once, and it worked out pretty well, but I used a combination of golden syrup and regular granulated brown sugar as a substitute. I got the idea from a friend who used molasses.

The ratio I used was around 1 tablespoon per cup of granular sugar.

The flavour was a little different but completely acceptable and may be better with molasses.